# Ebay findCompletedItems returning null

Tags: c#, null

I'm trying to query eBay with a FindCompletedItemRequest but the server is returning null

Heres the code

```
public static CustomFindingService FindingService(){
CustomFindingService findingService;
log.InfoFormat("Connect to Ebay: START");

findingService = new CustomFindingService("XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX");
findingService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

log.InfoFormat("Connect to Ebay: SUCCESS");
return findingService;
   }

var fcir = new FindCompletedItemsRequest {keywords = "5mp", categoryId =new string[] {"31388"}}; // 31388 is digital cameras
var l = FindingService().findCompletedItems(fcir);
```

I have tried removing categoryId and/switching the keywords nothing seems to help. Debugging has shown me that it is pinging the server just that the server is returning null.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest that you give the code for *CustomFindingService*. Being as it may I can take a shot at your problem anyway.

```
findingService = new CustomFindingService("XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX");
```

I'm guessing that this Generates the request in a similar manner to [Finding API - C#.NET code sample](https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1516/~/finding-api---c#.net-code-sample-to-call-finding-api-using-.net-framework.) with the appID being the series of X's. I am guessing that you forgot to change `request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsByKeywords");` to  `request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findCompletedItems");`. Simple solution would be to pass it the type of the request. For example.

```
public static CustomFindingService FindingService(string requestType){ // edit
CustomFindingService findingService;
log.InfoFormat("Connect to Ebay: START");

findingService = new CustomFindingService("XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX", requestType); // EDIT
findingService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

log.InfoFormat("Connect to Ebay: SUCCESS");
return findingService;
   }

var fcir = new FindCompletedItemsRequest {keywords = "5mp", categoryId =new string[] {"31388"}}; // 31388 is digital cameras
var l = FindingService(fcir.GetType().Name).findCompletedItems(fcir); // Edit
// Or since you know the Name already just skip the whole get type thing and pass it in directly.
```

Also,

```
log.InfoFormat("Connect to Ebay: SUCCESS");
return findingService;
```

I am fairy sure that this is incorrect. You don't conect while generating the request. Rather you connect during `var l = FindingService().findCompletedItems(fcir);`.

Comment: God bless you this has been a pain in my ... for a month and the answer was so simple